# How to group by 30 minutes interval in Databricks SQL

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, databricks-connect, databricks-community-edition

This is the function I was using to group by 30 mins of intervals in SQL:

`convert(time(0),dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.Datetime)/30)*30,0))`

where for example Datetime is `2023-03-09 00:26:01.6830000` grouped as 00:00:00.

First column values are the Datetime and second is after grouping it to 30 mins intervals

I need equivalent function in Databricks SQL.

Comment: Can you show readers what you have tried so far, or where in the documentation you are looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query works for the data in sql server:

```
select  *,convert(time(0),dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,t1.dt)/30)*30,0)) from t1;
```

[image]

- Its equivalent in databricks sql is as shown in the below query:

```
select  *,date_format(dateadd(minute,floor(datediff(minute,'1900-01-01',t1.dt)/30)*30,'1900-01-01'),'HH:mm:ss') from t1;
```

[image]